# How do I prevent the AsyncFileUpload from sending the file again on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asyncfileupload

I am developing an application that manages a photo contest. In that application, I use an AsyncFileUpload control for the user selected photo. The server-side UploadedComplete does basic validation, and scales/clip the image as necessary.

The problem is, when i click on the submit button on the page, the content of the AsyncFileUpload gets sent with the other user-submitted data, so the user gets to wait twice as long to get a response from the server (I'm expecting photos that are between 3 and 7 Mb big, which takes a minute or two to upload).

My form looks like that:

```
<%-- ... snip - all other fields ... -->
<div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="texteB"><b>Upload a photo</b></span><br />
    Browse your computer to find a photo.</div>
<div>
    <asp:AsyncFileUpload onclientuploaderror="UploadError" persistfile="true" onuploadedcomplete="fuPhoto_UploadedComplete"
        completebackcolor="#52ad0b" onclientuploadstarted="UploadStarted" id="fuPhoto"
        throbberid="throbber" runat="server" />
</div>
<div runat="server" id="throbber" style="display: none; margin: 8px 0 15px 0">
    <div style="float: left; width: 48px;">
        <img src="images/throbber.gif" /></div>
    <span class="texteV_14pt"><b>Please wait while
        <br />
        your photo is uploaded...</b></span>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    Please double-check your informations and press Send when ready.</div>
<div>
    <asp:ImageButton onclick="btnSubmit_Click" ImageUrl="images/bt_envoyer_demande.gif"
        runat="server" id="btnSubmit" />
</div>
```

Is there something I missed out in the documentation? I've been working on this all day without much success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AsyncFileUpload` doesn't really work like this. It only really works when you use the filedata in the `OnUploadedComplete` event.

I'd just bite the bullet and use something like SWFUpload or just use a native `FileUpload` control.

Comment: I ended up using a very terrible IFrame hack due to deadline glooming, but if I checked SWFUpload and it could have done the job for me. I just had all the code working already and a simple 5 line "hack" seemed correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool _justDeleted = false;

void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (_justDeleted) return;
```

---

```
protected void btnDeleteLogo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _justDeleted = true;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)